# How to give input to a maven dependency plugin by using another plugin

Tags: java, maven

I use maven-dependency-plugin to copy jar files of artifactItems, by giving artifactItem details at pom.xml as shown below

```
                <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactItems>

                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>junit</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                                            <version>3.8.2</version>
                                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                                            <destFileName>junit.jar</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                            </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>
```

can i use a plugin inside `<configuration> </configuration>` tag to give `<artifactItems></artifactItems>` dynamically,instead of giving it manually.

Comment: Can you elaborate more what you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for showing  interest in my question? What I meant is I want to call a plugin which will give me the artifact items . So can I provide my plugin inside the maven-dependency-plugin?

Comment: And what is the purpose of that? Do you like to deploy them to somewhere or what would you like to achieve?

Comment: instead of manually giving the artifact   details i wish to dynamically load them using another plugin which i want to provide inside the maven dependency plugin

Comment: You know that maven will download all dependencies automatically...?

Comment: Yes..,  my question is can i call a maven plugin from another maven plugin......?

Comment: So if i got your pom correctly you would likte to provide information about artifacts (GAV) from somewhere else and provide them to other plugins and download those artifact? But the question is: Where is this somewhere? Why not using the pom file? I don't the real advantage? Furthermore what about taking a look to Aether lib to download artifacts?